# C program counting occurrences of characters in string

Tags: c

this is my first time asking something in StackOverflow, usually i find my questions already answered here.

I have this code that needs to print the times of occurences of each character in a given word. I have been assigned to change only the code in the functions `report()` and `letters()` . This is what I have come up to trying and searching the past hours. I sense that the program is not working due to not freeing or accessing memory the right way.

Also, I am a bit confused on where exactly the `ListofChar chars` and `ListofChar lst_ptr`  pointers are pointing exactly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct charact {
    char ch;
    int occurs;
    struct charact *next;
};


typedef struct charact Char;
typedef Char * ListofChar;
typedef Char * CharNode_ptr;
void letters(char name[50], ListofChar * chars_ptr);
void report(ListofChar chars);
Char * createnode(char ch);


int main() {
    char name[50];
    ListofChar chars = NULL;
    scanf("%s", name);
    letters(name, &chars);
    report(chars);
    return 0;
}


Char * createnode(char ch) {
    CharNode_ptr newnode_ptr ;
    newnode_ptr = malloc(sizeof (Char));
    newnode_ptr -> ch = ch;
    newnode_ptr -> occurs = 0;
    newnode_ptr -> next = NULL;
    return newnode_ptr;
}


void letters(char name[50],ListofChar * lst_ptr) {
    ListofChar current  = lst_ptr ;
    int i=0  , j=0 ;
    for( i= 0 ; i < 50 ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < strlen(name) ; j++){
            if(current->ch  == name[i]){
                current->occurs++;
                break; }

            else if ( current-> ch == '\0' ){
                current-> ch = name[i];
                current-> occurs ++;
                break;  }
        }
    }
    return;
}





void report(ListofChar chars) {

    while((*chars).ch != '\0' )
        printf("%c  %d \n",(*chars).ch,(*chars).occurs);

    return;
}
```

Comment: I remember seeing this code here before

Comment: Are you related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168299/represent-a-pointer ?

Comment: I posted before but as someone correctly pointed out i hadnt filled out my own code on the functions. I reupoloaded correctly(i think)

Comment: Can you give some details of what is going wrong? Crash? Hang? Compiler errrors? Segfault? Wrong behaviour? Wrong output? What is desired output? What is current output? Please provide sample input (as background for the output comparison).

Comment: `report` is an endless loop. The list pointer is never moved to another node besides the first.  Unrelated, if you instructor tells you hiding pointer types behind typedefs is a good practice, ask them *when* and *why*, because there are only two cases where it makes sense, and this is neither. It makes the code *harder* to read and understand; not easier.

Comment: The question linked by Charles and its answers provide a nice explanation of what the pointers mean. (Sorry for saying so as the author of one of the answers....).

Comment: If the three `typedef`s were written by your teacher that is a crime, especially when using the confusing base type name `Char`. The second and third `typedefs` are identical, which only adds to the confusion. We don't like to `typedef` pointers, but if you do - make it clear in its name that it is a pointer (the third one does try that). What you could do, in making your solution, is to change the names of all those `typedef`s to something clearer while you work, and change them back when you submit your work. "we can't change XXX" yes you can while working - for a stepping stone.

Comment: The compiler generates one very important warning when compiling your code. That warning is related to the horrible typedef's that WeatherVane mentioned, and you need to fix it before you'll be able to get anywhere.

Comment: Please add the compiler warnings as important additional information to your question.

Comment: Minor: signed/unsigned mismatch comparing `int` with `strlen`.

Comment: By the way, you did well in putting some own code into the functions before asking. I just mention because I probably was the one telling you to do so and I hope it did not seem too harsh. You just have to add more information on the actual problem. Maybe this is a helpful article on the topic: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: First of all thanks for the kind responses. The answer that  Yunnosch provided on the similar question (wich was not me) kind of explains some of my confusion . What WhozCraig is saying that report is endless is true , about not moving to the next node , the problem is i dont understand the logic behind doing it , because i think it is needed to the letters functions as well. The compiler does not indicate errors ,  just not printing anything ....yet.